# Visual Studio 2008 window form closes immediately after opening

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Within my Visual Studio 2008 VB.Net project I am opening multiple forms after setting the form (that is opening) to be an mdichild of the main form. This works in really well in most of my forms except one. I am doing the exact same thing for all of them.

Basically I declare the new form:

```
Using frm As New frmName() With {.variableName = currentVariable}
  frm.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
  frm.openForm()
End Using
```

Within the `openForm` subroutine in the form code I have:

```
Public Sub openForm()
  InitializeDataSources()
  ...   ...
  Me.Show()
End Sub
```

I know this works because if I remove `frm.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent` in the main form and change `Me.Show()` to `Me.ShowDialog()` in the child form then it works perfectly. Right now (for only one form) it shows the form for only a second (looks like a flicker when staring at the program) and then closes it.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't know what `USING` is for in VB, but in C# it is disposing the object created by the statement when the execution exists the block.
If the purpose is the same, then this is the answer: you are creating the form:

`Using frm As New frmName()`

then you show it but when

```
End Using
```

is executed your form will be disposed, that is, closed.